# Canvas in react not rerendering every props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-video, react-hooks

I have been trying to implement a scroll video parallax effect inspired by [Apple's landing page](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-16/) 
in React.js. I have gotten pretty close following these references:

https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc/

http://www.petecorey.com/blog/2019/08/19/animating-a-canvas-with-react-hooks/

However when scrolling, the frame only updates when I stop scrolling. My desired result for the canvas is to render in a fluid like fashion while scrolling. In other words the frame should be updating every time my `props.scrollPos` updates.

All that's important to know about the parent is that it's passing a scroll position using `scrollTop`. This component is suppose to be reusable and work relative to its parent which is why I chose to not keep a scroll state internally.

You can view a working example of my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-meninsky-fo437?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) on CodeSandbox

ParallaxVideo.js

```
...

// request animation frame
// when scrollpos updates the current frame needs to change and cause rerender
// frame = (scrollPos - offset) / playbackConst

const ParallaxVideo = props => {
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    let requestId;
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d")
    const offset = heightRef.current.offsetTop
    videoRef.current.currentTime = (props.scrollPos - offset) / playbackConst
    console.log(props.scrollPos)

    const render = () => {
      context.drawImage(videoRef.current, 0, 0)
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(render)
    }

    render()


    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestId)
  })


  return (
    <div 
      style={{height: scrollHeight}}
      ref={heightRef}
    >
      <VideoWrap>
        <Video
          muted
          preload={preload}
          autoPlay={autoPlay} 
          loop={loop} 
          ref={videoRef}
          fitToScreen={fitToScreen}
          onLoadedMetadata={updateHeight}
          playsInline
        >
          {props.children}
        </Video>
        <Canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
      </VideoWrap>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for sure will not change the useEffect should have a inputs set to listen for changes,

```
useEffect(() => {
    let requestId;
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d")
    const offset = heightRef.current.offsetTop
    videoRef.current.currentTime = (props.scrollPos - offset) / playbackConst
    console.log(props.scrollPos)

    const render = () => {
      context.drawImage(videoRef.current, 0, 0)
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(render)
    }

    render()


    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestId)
  },[props.scrollPos])
```